# Is it possible to use an USB webcam with Snap?

Tags: usb, webcam, camera

My laptop has a built-in camera that's always being used by the Snap. If I plug a USB camera I can't switch to this one no matter what I do. Is it possible at all? I don't see any menu on Snap.

I've tried with other camera apps like `cheese` and I can switch in there but the change only affects that app and not Snap. I'm using Loki Stable, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Ubuntu loads drivers for builtin cameras via its kernel on default

Check with 'lsmod' for the driver wich s loaded like for example `uvcvideo`

Unload it with `sudo rmmod uvcvideo`

Then plug the usb-cam in and see if it works and check for the driver again.
If you want to use your builtin camera again which uses `uvcvideo` run

`sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

If you want to config your laptop to just use the usb-webcam permamently then change your `etc/modules` files to load the right driver.

Here are some infos howto change Loadable Modules:
[Ubuntu - Loadable_Modules](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules)

Comment: That doesn't do anything. I mean, the built-in webcam uses uvcvideo (I know because it doesn't let me unload the driver while Snap is open) but when I unload the driver and go back again to Snap it continues showing the same webcam no matter what.

Comment: forget my previous comment... it actually shows "there is no webcam available" when i disable the uvcvideo module.

Comment: Do you know wich driver your usb-cam needs?

Comment: I think both use uvcvideo since when i disable it the webcams don't work. By the way, my usb webcam is a Logitech C270

Comment: wich usb camera do you use could you give me the exact name please?

Comment: You can try to disable the builtin cam leike in this thread:

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/982265/how-to-disable-a-specific-faulty-laptop-webcam-in-ubuntu

Comment: You have to disable thi builtin cam if you check http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices the Logitech C270 also uses uvcvideo

Comment: Did this link http://superuser.com/questions/982265/how-to-disable-a-specific-faulty-laptop-webcam-in-ubuntu

Comment: Help or does the problem still exist?

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Later I'll edit your question with the correct steps so you get the points!